# How to Setup ASL Solvers in Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I am using Pyomo on Windows. I wanted to use nonlinear solvers such as BONMIN and I noticed that they are available using ASL. How can I use ASL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solver installation can be tricky on Windows, but you will want to:

1. install the relevant ASL solver
2. add its executable to your system path
3. call it from Pyomo

Each of these steps should have pre-existing documentation.

Comment: Thanks Qi. I will follow the steps. Some information for installing solvers like BONMIN can be found at https://projects.coin-or.org/Bonmin/wiki/GettingStarted